# Efficiently resetting an object by constructing new and assigning?

Tags: c++

Sometimes I reset an object by creating a new object and assigning it to the one you want to reset:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(void* parent) : parent(parent) {}
    void* parent;
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0;

    void reset()
    {
        *this = Foo(parent); // KEEP THE SAME PARENT
    }
};
```

There are couple of questions I have about doing this:

1. It seems what the compiler is doing is writing to a temporary object and then calling the assignment operation. Although this is convenient, is this less efficient than going `a = 0; b = 0; c = 0;` etc? Because that way we'd only be writing once.
2. In `*this = Foo(parent);` is there any optimization that the compiler does, like for example writing directly to the final destination object? If we do `Foo f = Foo();` then according to copy elision rules only one constructor may be called. But I guess in my `reset()` example no extra optimizations are possible?

Comment: Is there a destructor, or is this example snippet representative?  (I'm thinking of the situation that the destructor interoperates with the parent, to tell the parent that the child is destructed.  Say, such as if/when the parent has a vector of pointers to children and has to keep that up to date.)

Comment: I don't think there is a better way unless you use placement new, but you may leak resources.

Comment: @JuanR Just placement new would be UB. You would have to call the destructor first. And that will easily be worse than move assignment.

Comment: Does it matter? https://godbolt.org/z/f17Tv4Ga8 Unless your move assignment has side effects it just gets optimized out. When your move assignment gets so complex that it doesn't get optimized out then you can implement a more streamlined `reset()`.

Comment: Is there a reason why `reset()` cant just set all the variables to zero?

Answer (score 2):

In general case, copy elision cannot be applied here, since compiler has to destruct a current object first.
Why wouldn't you just initialize your vars in `reset`, and call `reset` from ctor? This approach has the same performance, less error-prone and has a lower WTF-metric.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can avoid the cost of constructing and destructing a temporary object. @Maskim Demianov is correct – the simplest and cheapest strategy would be to just initialize your `int` vars in `reset()`. And there's no need to call `reset()` from the constructor if you zero-initialize your data members:

```
struct Foo {
    void* parent {};
    int a {};
    int b {};
    int c {};
    int d {};
    int e {};
    Foo(void* parent) : parent(parent) {}
    void reset() {
        a = b = c = d = e = 0;
    }
};
```